# <!doctype html> backward compatibility

Tags: javascript, html

Everything is normal in chrome and IE9, but not in IE8.

Firstly, I set the HTML page with HTML5 template. Secondly, I init the `<iframe>` with an external Js document.

Then, an error occurs in IE8, reporting that the DOM element is undefined, and it displays while back the page to HTML4.01 template. I have checked for HTML5 top declaration, and it is backward compatibility.

Why IE8 didn't tell the page?

Comment: I say it's line 19 of your source code. Maybe 52, too.

Comment: Please be more clear in what you mean. What does "Tell the page" mean? What is exaclty your problem, what is the code, what have you tried, etc.

Comment: Please, stop ending every sentence with an exclamation mark. Try reading your question _out loud_, would someone who has never seen what you are working with be able to understand it? This question really needs editing for clarity, and it would help _immensely_ if you posted the relevant code. Otherwise, this question will quickly be closed.

Comment: If you can make the improvements to your question that were suggested, please flag your question for moderator review.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure you just need to add the [HTML5 shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) code in  your `<head>`:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```